# No termina update-database al hacer una actualización a la base de datos (migraciones)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, migration

Buenas tardes, bien tengo un proyecto que no es mío, pero le voy agregar un modulo, al revisar este proyecto vi que tiene Migraciones, entonces yo se que solo se configura el ConnectionString del app.config (aplicación de escritorio) con la dirección de mi base de datos y en consola pongo update-database

Eso hago pero se tarda y nunca termina, así lo deje y duro dos horas antes que lo cancelará, y solo son 11 tablas y ya.

Porque se tarda sin dar una respuesta??

```
> <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LSK_DBContext"
     connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=lsk-rest-desktop8; User ID=alex; Password=123456;Integrated Security=False;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

la base de datos en el sql server se llama "lsk-rest-desktop8", por su ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```
> <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LSK_DBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=lsk-rest-desktop8; User ID=alex; Password=123456;Integrated Security=False;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```